# $y' +2xy = 0$, dropping solutions during calculation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Given the equation $y' + 2xy = 0$, we can trivially see that $y=0$ is a solution, but when I try to solve the equation, this solution disappears.

We can separate and integrate:
$$\int \frac{dy}{y}=-2\int x\,dx\\ \\ \ln(y)=-x^2+c_1\\ \\ y=e^{-x^2 + c_1}$$
Now, before we do anything with this power, notice how the RHS cannot be zero, as it is a power of $e$.

When did the solution $y = 0$ disappear?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you have divided by y while separating variables you have assumed it is not equal to 0.

Comment: Ah, of course. Embarrassing.

Answer (score 2):

You missed an absolute value in the left anti-derivative,
$$
\ln|y|=-x^2+c.
$$
Then
$$
y=sign(y_0)e^{-x^2+c}=Ce^{-x^2}
$$
where $C=sign(y_0)e^{c}$. If you now also include the value $C=0$ you get the complete set of solutions including the previously excluded zero solution.

Comment: But given that $C = sign(y)e^c$, isn't $C=0$ still impossible?

Comment: No, while this part of the calculation only gives $C\ne 0$, on the other hand you already know that the zero function is a solution, so you add it to the solution family by also allowing $C=0$.

Answer (score 2):

Another way, where you have not to divide by a "thing" which can be zero!

The ODE is linear  with integral factor $e^{x^2}
$.  Hence, after multiplying both sides by such factor, we get 
$$D(e^{x^2}y(x))=(y'(x) + 2xy(x))e^{x^2} = 0$$
and after integration we obtain
$$e^{x^2}y(x)=c$$
and therefore  the general solution is
$$y(x)=ce^{-x^2}$$
where $c\in \mathbb{R}$.